# setExposureMode xcode iOS 8

Tags: xcode, camera, ios8

I am using the following code below to capture an image. Everything works fine but my commands to set the exposure and whitebalance in setCameraSettings() are ignored. They get executed but they have no effect. My command to set the session image resolution works fine.

```
#import "CaptureSessionManager.h"
#import <ImageIO/ImageIO.h>

// based on https://github.com/jj0b/AROverlayImageCapture

@implementation CaptureSessionManager

@synthesize captureSession;
@synthesize previewLayer;
@synthesize stillImageOutput;
@synthesize stillImage;
@synthesize imageWidth;
@synthesize imageHeight;
@synthesize imageBrightnessValue;
@synthesize imageExposureTime;
@synthesize imageApertureValue;
@synthesize imageISOSpeedRatings;
@synthesize playShutterSound;
/*************************************************************************************/
- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    //        [session beginConfiguration];
        if ([session canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh]) {
            session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh; // AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh; // AVCaptureSessionPresetLow;
        }
    //        [session commitConfiguration];
        [self setCaptureSession:session];
    } 
    return self;
}
/*************************************************************************************/
- (void)addVideoPreviewLayer {
    [self setPreviewLayer:[[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession: [self captureSession]]];
    [[self previewLayer] setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
}
/*************************************************************************************/

- (void)addVideoInputFrontCamera:(BOOL)front {
    NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devices];
    AVCaptureDevice *frontCamera;
    AVCaptureDevice *backCamera;

    for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices) {

        NSLog(@"Device name: %@", [device localizedName]);

        if ([device hasMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {

            if ([device position] == AVCaptureDevicePositionBack) {
                NSLog(@"Device position : back");
                backCamera = device;
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"Device position : front");
                frontCamera = device;
            }
        }
    }

    NSError *error = nil;

    if (front) {
        AVCaptureDeviceInput *frontFacingCameraDeviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:frontCamera error:&error];
        if (!error) {
            if ([[self captureSession] canAddInput:frontFacingCameraDeviceInput]) {
                [[self captureSession] addInput:frontFacingCameraDeviceInput];
                currentCaptureDevice = frontCamera;
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Couldn't add front facing video input");
            }
        }
    } else {
        AVCaptureDeviceInput *backFacingCameraDeviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:backCamera error:&error];
        if (!error) {
            if ([[self captureSession] canAddInput:backFacingCameraDeviceInput]) {
                [[self captureSession] addInput:backFacingCameraDeviceInput];
                currentCaptureDevice = backCamera;
           } else {
                NSLog(@"Couldn't add back facing video input");
            }
        }
    }
}
/*************************************************************************************/

- (void)addStillImageOutput
{
    [self setStillImageOutput:[[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init]];
    NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:AVVideoCodecJPEG,AVVideoCodecKey,nil];
    [[self stillImageOutput] setOutputSettings:outputSettings];

    [[self captureSession] addOutput:[self stillImageOutput]];

    for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in [[self stillImageOutput] connections]) {
        for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts]) {
            if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {
                videoConnection = connection;
                [self setCameraSettings];
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
/*************************************************************************************/

- (void)setCameraSettings:(long)expTime1000thSec iso:(int)isoValue
{
    if ( currentCaptureDevice ) {

        [captureSession beginConfiguration];

        NSError *error = nil;
        if ([currentCaptureDevice lockForConfiguration:&error]) {

            if ([currentCaptureDevice isExposureModeSupported:AVCaptureExposureModeLocked]) {

                CMTime minTime, maxTime, exposureTime;

                if ( isoValue < minISO ) {
                    isoValue = minISO;
                } else if ( isoValue > maxISO ) {
                    isoValue = maxISO;
                }

                exposureTime = CMTimeMake(expTime1000thSec, EXP_TIME_UNIT); // in 1/EXP_TIME_UNIT of a second
                minTime = currentCaptureDevice.activeFormat.minExposureDuration;
                maxTime = currentCaptureDevice.activeFormat.maxExposureDuration;

                if ( CMTimeCompare(exposureTime, minTime) < 0 ) {
                    exposureTime = minTime;
                } else if ( CMTimeCompare(exposureTime, maxTime) > 0 ) {
                    exposureTime = maxTime;
                }

                NSLog(@"setting exp time to %lld/%d s (want %ld)   iso=%d", exposureTime.value, exposureTime.timescale, expTime1000thSec, isoValue);
                [currentCaptureDevice setExposureModeCustomWithDuration:exposureTime ISO:isoValue completionHandler:nil];
            }

            if (currentCaptureDevice.lowLightBoostSupported) {
                currentCaptureDevice.automaticallyEnablesLowLightBoostWhenAvailable = NO;
                NSLog(@"setting automaticallyEnablesLowLightBoostWhenAvailable = NO");
            }

            // lock the gains
            if ([currentCaptureDevice isWhiteBalanceModeSupported:AVCaptureWhiteBalanceModeLocked]) {
                currentCaptureDevice.whiteBalanceMode = AVCaptureWhiteBalanceModeLocked;
                NSLog(@"setting AVCaptureWhiteBalanceModeLocked");
            }

            // set the gains
            AVCaptureWhiteBalanceGains gains;
            gains.redGain = 1.0;
            gains.greenGain = 1.0;
            gains.blueGain = 1.0;

            AVCaptureWhiteBalanceGains normalizedGains = [self normalizedGains:gains];
            [currentCaptureDevice setWhiteBalanceModeLockedWithDeviceWhiteBalanceGains:normalizedGains completionHandler:nil];
            NSLog(@"setWhiteBalanceModeLockedWithDeviceWhiteBalanceGains g.red=%.2lf g.green=%.2lf g.blue=%.2lf",
                  normalizedGains.redGain, normalizedGains.greenGain, normalizedGains.blueGain);

            [currentCaptureDevice unlockForConfiguration];
        }
        [captureSession commitConfiguration];
    }
}

/*************************************************************************************/

- (void)captureStillImage
{

    NSLog(@"about to request a capture from: %@", [self stillImageOutput]);
    [[self stillImageOutput] captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection
                                                         completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {

                                                             CFDictionaryRef exifAttachments = CMGetAttachment(imageSampleBuffer, kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary, NULL);
                                                             if (exifAttachments) {
                                                                 NSLog(@"attachements: %@", exifAttachments);
                                                             } else {
                                                                 NSLog(@"no attachments");
                                                             }

                                                             NSLog(@"name: %@", [currentCaptureDevice localizedName]);

                                                             NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
                                                             UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
                                                             [self setStillImage:image];

                                                             NSDictionary *dict = (__bridge NSDictionary*)exifAttachments;
                                                             NSString *value = [dict objectForKey:@"PixelXDimension"];
                                                             [self setImageWidth:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[value intValue]]];

                                                             NSString *value1 = [dict objectForKey:@"PixelYDimension"];
                                                             [self setImageHeight:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[value1 intValue]]];

                                                             NSString *value2 = [dict objectForKey:@"BrightnessValue"];
                                                             [self setImageBrightnessValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[value2 floatValue]]];

                                                             NSString *value3 = [dict objectForKey:@"ExposureTime"];
                                                             [self setImageExposureTime:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[value3 floatValue]]];

                                                             NSString *value4 = [dict objectForKey:@"ApertureValue"];
                                                             [self setImageApertureValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[value4 floatValue]]];

                                                             NSArray *values = [dict objectForKey:@"ISOSpeedRatings"];
                                                             [self setImageISOSpeedRatings:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[ [values objectAtIndex:0] floatValue]]];

                                                             // must be at end
                                                             [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kImageCapturedSuccessfully object:nil];

                                                         }];

}
/********************************************************************************/

- (void)dealloc {

    [[self captureSession] stopRunning];

    //  [super dealloc];

}
/************************************************************************************/
@end
```

Comment: You may be sending a message to a null object. Check to see that the object you're sending the message to is non-null.

Comment: I check for currentCaptureDevice == nil and it is not nil.

Comment: I got it working and updated setCameraSettings()

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the device you want to use custom settings.
Like this :

```
if([device isExposureModeSupported:AVCaptureExposureModeCustom])
{
    [device setExposureMode:AVCaptureExposureModeCustom];
    [device setExposureModeCustomWithDuration:exposureTime ISO:exposureISO completionHandler:^(CMTime syncTime) {}];
    [device setExposureTargetBias:exposureBIAS completionHandler:^(CMTime syncTime) {}];    
}
```

You are skipping the setExposureMode..

Hope this works.

Comment: I added:

`[device setExposureMode:AVCaptureExposureModeCustom];`

and changed my completionHandler from nil to:

‘completionHandler:^(CMTime syncTime) {}’

and I still see the same results.

Comment: I changed the ISO in steps. I can set and get these values: 50, 64, 80, 100, 125, 160, 200, 250, 320, 400, 500, 640. Any values between these get clamped to the closest "standard" value. The camera reports that its min/max ISO is 46 and 736. If I sent it to 46 it reports in the EXIF as being 50. If I sent it to 736, in the EXIF it reports 800. If I set it to 800 it crashes.

Comment: Are you taking the image quickly after setting the exposure?

Comment: Documentation:

Calls to captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:completionHandler: are not synchronized with AVCaptureDevice
    manual control completion handlers. Setting a device manual control, waiting for its completion, then calling
    captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:completionHandler: DOES NOT ensure that the still image returned reflects
    your manual control change. 

So used the completion handler of the setCustom exposure settings to allow the user to capture the image.

Other more thing, make sure u are reading the minISO and maxISO from one cam and not both

Comment: I downloaded the AVCamManualUsingtheManualCaptureAPI example and when I set the exposure time to 0.8, it gets reported in the Exif as 1. If I set it to values less than 0.5 then I get the values I requested. I guess that's just how it works.

Comment: What i've found is that ExposureMode CANNOT be "custom" for the setExposureTargetBias setting to work. It's also fairly slow to update once changed, so it might not be reflected on the next few frames.

Comment: I believe the min and max ISO will vary from device to device? And how can I set the exposureDuration? As far as I know, the exposure is related to the brightness in the image?

Comment: In the answer, exposureTime is the exposure duration that you want to set and exposureISO is the iso you want to set. 
ISO and exposure time affect brightness. But ISO is 'kinda' a software brightness and exposure time is how much time you let the lens open so it can capture more light.